# How to create a folder in the GCP Bucket using API?

Tags: vb.net, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, cloud

I am not able to create a folder in the GCP Bucket, Is there any option to create a folder in the Bucket using API.

I am not able to create a folder in the GCP Bucket, Is there any option to create a folder in the Bucket using API.

Comment: GCS - object storage is completely flat. There are no 'folders' at all in the buckets. When you see a 'folder' in the console UI, it's just metadata describing how to depict such thing. If you create an object and make some prefixes with slashes in its name - they are going to be presented as 'folders' in the UI. See https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/folders for details.

Answer (score 0):

you don't create folder through API you can use you can create bucket through API, but you can create folder through `gsutil` command.

```bash
gsutil cp -r ./your-dir gs://your-bucket/new
```